# Animating other elements on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build an interactive wikipedia website for children and I want the wheels on my train and the steam from the train move when they hover over the train body. I'm trying to do this using JQuery or CSS.
But it's not working.  I managed to get each image to animate when you hover over the individual element, using CSS but it would look much better if I could have all 4 elements move when they hover over the train body only.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".stationaryTrain").hover(function() {
    $(".stationary").toggleClass("moveWheels");
    $(".still").toggleClass("move");
  });
});
```

```css
.stationaryTrain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#trainWheel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  left: 40.5%;
  z-index: 2;
}
#trainWheel2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  left: 47%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.moveWheels {
  -moz-animation: .6s rotateRight infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: .6s rotateRight infinite linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
#steam1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38%;
  left: 48%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: margin 3s ease;
  -moz-transition: margin 3s ease;
  -o-transition: margin 3s ease;
  -ms-transition: margin 3s ease;
  transition: margin 3s ease;
}
#steam2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 48.5%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: margin 3s ease;
  -moz-transition: margin 3s ease;
  -o-transition: margin 3s ease;
  -ms-transition: margin 3s ease;
  transition: margin 3s ease;
}
.move {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trainCont">
  <img src="images/trainBody.jpg" alt="trnBdy" id="trainBody" style="width:10%;height:7%;" class="stationaryTrain">
</div>

<div id="trainWhlCont">
  <img src="images/wheel.jpg" alt="trnWhl" id="trainWheel" style="width:2.5%;height:2.5%;" class="stationary">
</div>

<div id="trainWhlCont2">
  <img src="images/wheel.jpg" alt="trnWhl" id="trainWheel2" style="width:2.5%;height:2.5%;" class="stationary">
</div>

<div id="steam1Cont">
  <img src="images/smoke1.jpg" alt="steam1" id="steam1" style="width:2%;height:3%;" class="still">
</div>

<div id="steam2Cont">
  <img src="images/smoke3.jpg" alt="steam1" id="steam2" style="width:2%;height:3%;" class="still">
</div>
```

Once I have this working i am also hoping to add in sounds of a steam train on hover.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure I'm making a minor error somewhere but I can't find it anywhere

Here is a JFiddle of how it is now: https://jsfiddle.net/mikehene/gtvbp0wy/

Comment: Make a fiddle/plunkr please

Comment: It seems to work, check your edited question. Have you added `$(".stationaryTrain").hover` inside DOM ready ??

Comment: Hi Pugazh. Yeah I've got dom ready and I also have my script at the bottom of the page

Comment: Patrick, i'm trying to make a fiddle but can't get the images to load in

Comment: Patrick, here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mikehene/gtvbp0wy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the animation of the inner elements when their parent is hovered like this:

```
.stationaryTrain:hover .stationary{
    -moz-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; 
    -webkit-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; 
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

Do that for each of them, for ex.:

```
.stationaryTrain:hover .still{
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: Hey Velimir, I implemented the above code but it hasn't worked unfortunately

Comment: Velimir, I implemented your changes in JSFiddle but its not working, you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/mikehene/gtvbp0wy/

Comment: where's the `:hover` directive in the fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z61hdbyy/ this works, keep in mind that `-webkit-animation` won't work on other than webkit browsers. I'm not getting why someone downvoted

Comment: It's at the bottom of the CSS, I tried using .stationaryTrain:hover .still{
    margin-top: -50px;
} https://jsfiddle.net/mikehene/gtvbp0wy/

Comment: anyways check out this fiddle - jsfiddle.net/z61hdbyy I'm not going into details but you didn't quite get the idea of the animate function - check this link out to get a better grasp http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: I understand how animations work. The animation works when I toggle the class manually(hard code), but its the JQuery toggle class that is not functioning.

Comment: in the fiddle you hadn't included the jquery right. In my fiddle your jquery code works exactly as intended and I only changed the css

Comment: for example if I change the class name of stationary to "stationary moveWheels" the wheels move

Comment: Yeah, the JQuery was in there too.

Comment: Could you post a link to the jsfiddle where you changed the CSS and it worked as it's not for me. Thanks